# How can I determine which packages I have installed via homebrew and which were installed manually?

Tags: macos, homebrew

I have a number of packages installed on my mac.  Is there a terminal command that will allow me to determine which packages were installed via Homebrew?

For instance, I have R and git on my mac, but I know that neither R nor git were installed via Homebrew.  Is there any other way to figure out which other packages were / weren't installed via Homebrew?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`brew list` will show you what formulae you've installed.  For each of those you can use `brew list` *formula* to show which files were installed from that formula.

Answer (score 3):

If you only want what you actually installed, and not also the (possibly hundreds of) dependencies that came with it: `brew leaves`.

That list is much nicer for re-installing things.

Comment: Thanks for adding this wisdom 8 years after the original post, this was exactly what I was looking for!